# Woocommerce Add dynamically new custom Fields on Click

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add a new custom Field in the Woocommerce Edit Product Page. But I want it to be added on click. So that when I click "Add new" it adds a new custom input field. So that I don't have to add 100 Fields, but always just add as many as I need.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: This link should help you: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-custom-product-fields-woocommerce/

Comment: Honestly I would just use the plugin "Advanced Custom Fields" and create a Repeater field that shows on products. It will save you a ton of time.